# AWS python Flask EB .ebextensions .conf file is not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

.conf file

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_proxy.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 200M;

container_commands:                         
  01_reload_nginx:                           
    command: "sudo nginx -s reload"
```

I have put this file in all possible folders:

```
.ebextensions
|-- 01_nginx.conf
|
|--nginx
   |--01_nginx.conf
   |--conf.d
      |--01_nginx.conf
```

when I check the log, the first message is

> 2020/07/31 18:23:59.603405 [INFO] Finished executing the config set Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild.

then

> 2020/07/31 18:23:59.603427 [INFO] Executing instruction: CleanEbExtensions

In theory when .ebextensions is cleant the custom commands should already have been executed, but they are not (when I connect via ssh to the server no file has been created as well as if I try to upload files, the server responds with a 413).

I have also tried modifying the nginx.conf file in /etc/nginx/ but it is reset everytime I update the code.
All the /etc/nginx/ directory seems to be reset because I have also tried to put a "000_custom.conf" file in "/etc/nginx/conf.d/", but with no results.

Edit:
I'd like to point out that if I modify nginx.conf in "/etc/nginx/" on the server and I do a "sudo nginx -s reload" it works till the next code build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely reason why your nginx config does not work is that you are using current version of EB which is based on **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2). However, your nginx config files are for AL1, which is old.

For AL2, nginx settings should be in `.platform`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you could try creating file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/mynginx.conf` with the content of:

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```